# django and javascript API

Tags: javascript, python, django, api, geolocation

I would like to use this javascript API in a Django based web page. Is it possible to use this code below in a Django web framework?

https://github.com/Esri/html5-geolocation-tool-js

I plan to create a web page where users can sign up and log in to the Django webpage and subsequently upload their photos and post their live user location from their mobile phone into their own web account. I need to use this API as it has an accuracy of up to 10 meters outdoors which is ideal for my application. I only really need the latitude and longitude data from the GPS to be saved in Django.

I have only around 6 months of Python and Django experience and none for javascript. Any advice on how to integrate this API into Django?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this is a Q&A forum where programming questions can be asked and answered. This is **not** a code writing service or a debug service for pretty specific questions. If you need a code to be written, than please rent a developer (-> www.google.de/search?q=rent+a+developer)

Comment: you can import any js script in your django templates, you can more or less consider them as a rich html file, but still a html file. I don't see a reason why you couln't use this library

Comment: Hille, noted on your message, still new here. But thank you.           Thank you Elio. I will give it a try. Is there any tutorial or blog page which might help?